# Will canceling InnoDB compression that's already in progress corrupt data?

Tags: mysql, innodb, corruption, compression

I have a 155GB table that is in the process of being compressed.

```
ALTER TABLE $table_name ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

This compression has been running for a long time and is impeding my ability to backup.

I'm thinking about killing the compression query, backing up, and trying the compression again once my devs know how long it'll be till the next backup.

Is there any danger in just running a kill statement? Is there a safe way to back out of this compression?

My fear is that backing out of a compression mid query will corrupt the table. I would like to run the following query below but I believe it will be dangerous.

```
KILL QUERY 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is enabled, then a temp table is being populated with the new compression. The original table is currently intact, just not writable.

Running `KILL QUERY 12345` on the Connection running the `ALTER TABLE` should do the following:

- release the write lock
- drop the temp table
- leave the original table as is

Comment: innodb_file_per_table is enabled. So to clarify. Currently, all alterations are being done to the tmp table, and a kill to the query won't touch the physical "non-tmp" table?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. The temp table should have the filename `#sql-?????.ibd`. You can kill the `ALTER TABLE` and that file should disappear. Hurry before it finishes ...